# How do I fix the following problem in Arabic?

Tags: tables, arabic, compilation-error

I am trying to compile a tex file that has some arabic.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acl2018}

\usepackage{arabtex}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
aa
\end{abstract}

\begin{tabular}{l}
\arab{A}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The style file acl2018.sty can be found in here: http://acl2018.org/downloads/acl18-latex.zip

For some reason, the following errors happen (they seem to be unrelated):

1. An error with the abstract command.
2. An error with the \arab command (probably because it is inside of a table? but not sure how to fix)
3. The Arabic letter doesn't actually show up. Instead 0 shows up.

Any ideas how to fix that? My impression is that it is related to the list environment somehow, but not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `\arab{}` command in `arabtex`.  Use `\RL{}` instead, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{acl2018}

\usepackage{arabtex}
\setarab

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
aa
\end{abstract}

\begin{tabular}{l}
\RL{A}
\end{tabular}
```

Also, remember to compile your document with `pdflatex`.